# BBEdit-compatible regex for remove blank lines

Tags: regex, bbedit

i've tried other regexes that are supposed to be able to remove blank lines from a document, but none of them seem to work within BBEdit's find-and-replace.

What is a regex for stripping blank lines from a document that will work in bbedit?

Answer (score 16):

I'm going to assume that there may be whitespace in the lines you wish to remove. This should do the trick:

```
^\s*?\r
```

(replace with nothing, make sure the "Grep" checkbox is ticked)

Answer (score 6):

I find it easier to choose "Text>Process lines containing..." with the expression:

```
^$
```

or

```
^\s*$
```

Check the "Use grep" and "Delete matched lines" box. Uncheck all others.

Comment: There is no 'Delete matched lines' option in BBEdit 12.

Comment: @DawnSong first select "Text>Process lines containing...", in the dialog box that appears there is a checkbox "Delete matched lines" (at least in my version of BBEdit 12)

Comment: Your method only works on lines containing at least one space symbol. If the line contains nothing, your method won't work.

Comment: @DawnSong I'm getting the same result (erases only lines with one or more space), but that doesn't make sense, as `*` should [match zero or one](https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/wd/regexp.html). What's up there? Looks like the $ requires a second line -- when I did a search & replace with the same regex (`^\s*$`), it removed all but the last line in each batch of empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

This works in Coda. (Not sure about BBEdit though)

Find:

```
\n\n
```

Replace with:

```
\n
```

Make sure the "Use Regular Expressions" option is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Find: \r+
Replace with: \r

Grep option should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

BBEdit..
Text --> process duplicate lines. Delete duplicate lines

Answer (score 0):

To remove all blank lines whatever the amount of blank lines between not blank lines, whatever the amount been regular or not.

You must proceed that way:

1st you remove all the blank lines with

```
 « Text Menu / Process Lines Containing... »
 > Regex : ^$
 > Use grep enabled
 > Delete matched line enabled
```

2d if you want to recover legibility add a blank line after your blocks for instance

```
 « Search Menu / Find... »
 > Grep enabled
 > Find: ^}$        <<<< because the final curly is usually the 1st and the last char
 > Replace: }\n     <<<< or \r or \r\c according to the Platform choice
```

Answer (score 0):

For truly blank lines in BBedit, I search for:

```
^$\r
```

and replace with nothing. This finds the blank lines and removes the contents of the line and the linefeed.

An alternative I have used when I forget how to match a linefeed is to use:

```
.+
```

…to match one or more characters and then use the extract button rather than replace all. Instead of deleting your blank lines, you are keeping any line with something on it.